# j-query function to update value onchange

Tags: jquery, html

I am very new to programming world. I have written the following code to calculate number of classes per faculty and total number of classes. But the code does not give the desired result. Any change in a particular row or column should effect only that row or column. Only the box in the South-East corner will be effected by change in any where. But in the present code one change effects all. How to fix it?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse" align="center">
            <caption>
                <h3>Assign Teacher</h3>
            </caption>

            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>MON</th>
                <th>TUE</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td> <b>Sem I Honours</b>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    <select id="" onchange="" >
                        <option></option>
                        <option id="">SP</option>
                        <option id="">AP</option>
                        <option id="">Guest</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <td align="center">
                    <select  id=""  onchange="">
                        <option></option>
                        <option id="">SP</option>
                        <option id="">AP</option>
                        <option id="">Guest</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <td>
                    Total:
                    <span class="cnt-total">0</span>
                    <br/>    
                    SP:
                    <span class="cnt-sp">0</span>
                    <br/>    
                    AP:
                    <span class="cnt-ap">0</span>
                    <br/>    
                    Guest:
                    <span class="cnt-guest">0</span>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td> <b>Sem III Honours</b>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    <select id="" onchange="">
                        <option></option>
                        <option id="">SP</option>
                        <option id="">AP</option>
                        <option id="">Guest</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <td align="center">
                    <select id="" onchange="">
                        <option></option>
                        <option id="">SP</option>
                        <option id="">AP</option>
                        <option id="">Guest</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <td>
                    Total:
                    <span class="cnt-total">0</span>
                    <br/>    
                    SP:
                    <span class="cnt-sp">0</span>
                    <br/>    
                    AP:
                    <span class="cnt-ap">0</span>
                    <br/>    
                    Guest:
                    <span class="cnt-guest">0</span>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>Total</b>
                </td>

                <td>
                    Total:
                    <span class="cnt-total">0</span>
                    <br/>    
                    SP:
                    <span class="cnt-sp">0</span>
                    <br/>    
                    AP:
                    <span class="cnt-ap">0</span>
                    <br/>    
                    Guest:
                    <span class="cnt-guest">0</span>
                </td>

                <td>
                    Total:
                    <span class="cnt-total">0</span>
                    <br/>    
                    SP:
                    <span class="cnt-sp">0</span>
                    <br/>    
                    AP:
                    <span class="cnt-ap">0</span>
                    <br/>    
                    Guest:
                    <span class="cnt-guest">0</span>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <b>Total:
                        <span class="cnt-total">0</span>
                        <br/>    
                        SP:
                        <span class="cnt-sp">0</span>
                        <br/>    
                        AP:
                        <span class="cnt-ap">0</span>
                        <br/>    
                        Guest:
                        <span class="cnt-guest">0</span></b> 
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <script>
            $('select').change(function() {
                // get all selects
                var allSelects = $('select'),
                    total = 0,
                    sp = 0,
                    ap = 0,
                    guest = 0;

                // for each select increase count
                $.each(allSelects, function(i, s) {
                    // increase count
                    if($(s).val() == 'SP') { total++ }
                    if($(s).val() == 'AP') { total++ }
                    if($(s).val() == 'Guest') { total++ }
                    if($(s).val() == 'SP') { sp++; }
                    if($(s).val() == 'AP') { ap++; }
                    if($(s).val() == 'Guest') { guest++; }
                });

                // update count values summary
                $('.cnt-total').text(total);
                $('.cnt-sp').text(sp);
                $('.cnt-ap').text(ap);
                $('.cnt-guest').text(guest);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: jQuery selectors e.g. `$('.cnt-total')` will return a _collection_ of DOM nodes. The method `.text()` will affect every member in that collection. The logic of your app probably needs work if this is not want you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This traversal/matrix math operation (or a simple count by key) is not so simple. You said you're new into programming, so I made an implementation using some basic javascript techniques. Also, I updated your html to use some `data-` attributes, just to allow some further customization.

### HTML

```
    <html>
    <head><script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script></head>
    <body>
    <table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse" align="center"><caption><h3>Assign Teacher</h3></caption>

     <tr><th></th><th>MON</th><th>TUE</th><th>Total</th></tr>

     <tr><td><b>Sem I Honours</b></td><td align="center"><select  id=""  onchange="" data-class="Sem I Honours" data-day="MON"><option></option><option      id="">SP</option><option  id="">AP</option><option id="">Guest</option></select>  </td>

      <td align="center"><select  id=""  onchange="" data-class="Sem I Honours" data-day="TUE"><option></option>
     <option id="">SP</option><option id="">AP</option><option    id="">Guest</option>
      </select></td>

      <td>
      Total:<span class="cnt-total" data-class="Sem I Honours" data-key="any" data-day="any">0</span><br/>
      SP:<span class="cnt-total" data-class="Sem I Honours" data-key="SP" data-day="any">0</span><br/>
      AP: <span class="cnt-total" data-class="Sem I Honours" data-key="AP" data-day="any">0</span><br/>
      Guest: <span class="cnt-total" data-class="Sem I Honours" data-key="Guest" data-day="any">0</span></td></tr>


    <tr><td><b>Sem III Honours</b></td>
    <td align="center"><select   id="" onchange="" data-class="Sem III Honours" data-day="MON"><option></option><option     id="">SP</option><option id="">AP</option><option id="">Guest</option></select>   </td>

    <td align="center"><select   id="" onchange="" data-class="Sem III Honours" data-day="TUE"><option></option><option   id="">SP</option><option id="">AP</option><option id="">Guest</option></select>  </td>

     <td>
     Total:<span class="cnt-total" data-class="Sem III Honours" data-key="any" data-day="any">0</span><br/>
     SP:<span class="cnt-total" data-class="Sem III Honours" data-key="SP" data-day="any">0</span><br/>
     AP: <span class="cnt-total" data-class="Sem III Honours" data-key="AP" data-day="any">0</span><br/>
     Guest: <span class="cnt-total" data-class="Sem III Honours" data-key="Guest" data-day="any">0</span>
     </td>
     </tr>

     <tr><td><b>Total</b></td>


    <td>
    Total:<span class="cnt-total" data-class="any" data-key="any" data-day="MON">0</span><br/>
    SP:<span class="cnt-total" data-class="any" data-key="SP" data-day="MON">0</span><br/>
    AP: <span class="cnt-total" data-class="any" data-key="AP" data-day="MON">0</span><br/>
    Guest: <span class="cnt-total" data-class="any" data-key="Guest" data-day="MON">0</span>
    </td>

    <td>
    Total:<span class="cnt-total" data-class="any" data-key="any" data-day="TUE">0</span><br/>
    SP:<span class="cnt-total" data-class="any" data-key="SP" data-day="TUE">0</span><br/>
    AP: <span class="cnt-total" data-class="any" data-key="AP" data-day="TUE">0</span><br/>
    Guest: <span class="cnt-total" data-class="any" data-key="Guest" data-day="TUE">0</span>
    </td>

    <td>
    Total:<span class="cnt-total" data-class="any" data-key="any" data-day="any">0</span><br/>
    SP:<span class="cnt-total" data-class="any" data-key="SP" data-day="any">0</span><br/>
    AP: <span class="cnt-total" data-class="any" data-key="AP" data-day="any">0</span><br/>
    Guest: <span class="cnt-total" data-class="any" data-key="Guest" data-day="any">0</span>
    </td>

     </tr>

    </table>

<script><!-- script here --></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Javascript

```
<script>

(function() {


    var data = {};

    function resetData() {
        data = {};
    }

    function updateDataFromSelects() {
        resetData();
        $('select').each(function() {       
            var this_class = $(this).attr("data-class");
            var this_day = $(this).attr('data-day');
            if (typeof data[this_class] === "undefined") data[this_class] = {};
             data[this_class][this_day] = $(this).val();
        });
        updateTotals();
    }

    function updateTotals() {

        $('span.cnt-total').each(function() {
            var this_key = $(this).attr('data-key');
            var this_day = $(this).attr('data-day');
            var this_class = $(this).attr('data-class');

            $(this).text(totalByKey(this_class, this_day, this_key));

        });



    }

    function totalByKey(_class,_day, _key) {
        var count = 0;
        for (class_key in data) {
            if (class_key === _class || _class === "any") {
                for (day_key in data[class_key]) {
                    if (day_key === _day || _day === "any") {
                        var key = data[class_key][day_key];
                        if (key.length === 0) continue;
                        if (key === _key || _key === "any") count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }


    function bind() {

        $('select').change(function() {
            updateDataFromSelects();
        });


    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        bind();
        updateDataFromSelects();
    });


})();


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy your text `option` to `value` attribute in all selects, and your js script should work correctly

```
<select id="" onchange="" >
    <option></option>
    <option value="SP">SP</option>
    <option value="AP">AP</option>
    <option value="Guest">Guest</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
function calcTable(){
    var $table = $('table');

  var sum = function($select, obj) {
    if($select.val() == 'SP') { obj.total++ }
    if($select.val() == 'AP') { obj.total++ }
    if($select.val() == 'Guest') { obj.total++ }
    if($select.val() == 'SP') { obj.sp++; }
    if($select.val() == 'AP') { obj.ap++; }
    if($select.val() == 'Guest') { obj.guest++; }

    return obj;
  };

  var res = function($selector, obj){
    if(obj == undefined) return;

    $selector.find('.cnt-total').text(obj.total);
    $selector.find('.cnt-sp').text(obj.sp);
    $selector.find('.cnt-ap').text(obj.ap);
    $selector.find('.cnt-guest').text(obj.guest);
  };

  var count_cols = $table.find('tr:eq(1) td').length,
    count_rows = $table.find('tr').length;
    cols = [],
    rows = [];

  for(var row = 1; row < count_rows-1; row++){
    for(var col = 1; col < count_cols-1; col++){
        var cell = $table.find('tr:eq('+row+') td:eq('+col+')'),
        $select = cell.find('select');
      if(!rows[row]){
        rows[row] = { total: 0, sp: 0, ap: 0, guest: 0 };
      }
      if(!cols[col]){
        cols[col] = { total: 0, sp: 0, ap: 0, guest: 0 };
      }

      if($select.length){
        cols[col] = sum($select, cols[col]);
        rows[row] = sum($select, rows[row]);
      }
    }
  }

  $table.find('tr:eq(' + (count_rows-1) + ') td').each(function(i, td){
    res($(td), cols[i]);
  });

  $table.find('tr').each(function(i, tr){
    res($(tr).find('td:eq('+(count_cols-1)+')'), rows[i]);
  });

  //all
  var all = { total: 0, sp: 0, ap: 0, guest: 0 };
  for(var i in rows){
    all.total +=rows[i].total;
    all.sp +=rows[i].sp;
    all.ap +=rows[i].ap;
    all.guest +=rows[i].guest;
  }

  res($table.find('tr:eq('+(count_rows-1)+') td:eq('+(count_cols-1)+')'), all);
}

$('select').change(function() {
    calcTable();
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aqpwnjav/4/)

Comment: No this is not the desired result. Change in one row  (or column) should not effect the other row (or column).

Answer (score 0):

```
First you have to identify Display Result <td> like FirstSem , SecoundSem ,Total by class

For Sem I Honours Total Display...

<td class="Sem_first">
                Total:
                <span class="cnt-total">0</span>
                <br/>    
                SP:
                <span class="cnt-sp">0</span>
                <br/>    
                AP:
                <span class="cnt-ap">0</span>
                <br/>    
                Guest:
                <span class="cnt-guest">0</span>
            </td>

Sem III Honours Total Display...

<td class="Sem_Secound">
                Total:
                <span class="cnt-total">0</span>
                <br/>    
                SP:
                <span class="cnt-sp">0</span>
                <br/>    
                AP:
                <span class="cnt-ap">0</span>
                <br/>    
                Guest:
                <span class="cnt-guest">0</span>
            </td>

For total....

<td class="Sem_first">
                Total:
                <span class="cnt-total">0</span>
                <br/>    
                SP:
                <span class="cnt-sp">0</span>
                <br/>    
                AP:
                <span class="cnt-ap">0</span>
                <br/>    
                Guest:
                <span class="cnt-guest">0</span>
            </td>

            <td class="Sem_Secound">
                Total:
                <span class="cnt-total">0</span>
                <br/>    
                SP:
                <span class="cnt-sp">0</span>
                <br/>    
                AP:
                <span class="cnt-ap">0</span>
                <br/>    
                Guest:
                <span class="cnt-guest">0</span>
            </td>

            <td class="total">
                <b>Total:
                    <span class="cnt-total">0</span>
                    <br/>    
                    SP:
                    <span class="cnt-sp">0</span>
                    <br/>    
                    AP:
                    <span class="cnt-ap">0</span>
                    <br/>    
                    Guest:
                    <span class="cnt-guest">0</span></b> 
            </td>

not Also give class to each drop down

This is for first

 <td> <b>Sem I Honours</b>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <select id="" onchange="" class="Sem_1" >
                    <option></option>
                    <option id="">SP</option>
                    <option id="">AP</option>
                    <option id="">Guest</option>
                </select>
            </td>

            <td align="center">
                <select  id=""  onchange="" class="Sem_1">
                    <option></option>
                    <option id="">SP</option>
                    <option id="">AP</option>
                    <option id="">Guest</option>
                </select>
            </td>

This is for secound ... 

 <td> <b>Sem III Honours</b>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <select id="" onchange="" class="Sem_2" >
                    <option></option>
                    <option value="SP">SP</option>
                    <option value="AP">AP</option>
                    <option value="Guest">Guest</option>
                </select>
            </td>

            <td align="center">
                <select id="" onchange="" class="Sem_2" >
                    <option></option>
                    <option value="SP">SP</option>
                    <option value="AP">AP</option>
                    <option value="Guest">Guest</option>
                </select>
            </td>

Now Change is javascript...

 var allSelects = $(this)

if($(this).attr("class") == "Sem_1"){
                // For First Sem Row & column
                $(".Sem_first .cnt-total").text(total);
                $(".Sem_first .cnt-sp").text(sp);
                $(".Sem_first .cnt-ap").text(ap);
                $(".Sem_first .cnt-guest").text(guest);

            }
            if($(this).attr("class") == "Sem_2"){

                //For seound sem Row & column
                $(".Sem_Secound .cnt-total").text(total);
                $(".Sem_Secound .cnt-sp").text(sp);
                $(".Sem_Secound .cnt-ap").text(ap);
                $(".Sem_Secound .cnt-guest").text(guest);
            }      

            //For total

            $(".total .cnt-total").text(total);
            $(".total .cnt-sp").text(sp);
            $(".total .cnt-ap").text(ap);
            $(".total .cnt-guest").text(guest);



And comment your code ....

// update count values summary
           // $('.cnt-total').text(total);
           // $('.cnt-sp').text(sp);
           // $('.cnt-ap').text(ap);
           // $('.cnt-guest').text(guest);
```

**....    Here is full Code ......**

**JS**

```
 <script src=" http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
```

**HTML**

```
<table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse" align="center">
        <caption>
            <h3>Assign Teacher</h3>
        </caption>

        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>MON</th>
            <th>TUE</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> <b>Sem I Honours</b>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <select id="" onchange="" class="Sem_1" >
                    <option></option>
                    <option id="">SP</option>
                    <option id="">AP</option>
                    <option id="">Guest</option>
                </select>
            </td>

            <td align="center">
                <select  id=""  onchange="" class="Sem_1">
                    <option></option>
                    <option id="">SP</option>
                    <option id="">AP</option>
                    <option id="">Guest</option>
                </select>
            </td>

            <td class="Sem_first">
                Total:
                <span class="cnt-total">0</span>
                <br/>    
                SP:
                <span class="cnt-sp">0</span>
                <br/>    
                AP:
                <span class="cnt-ap">0</span>
                <br/>    
                Guest:
                <span class="cnt-guest">0</span>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> <b>Sem III Honours</b>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <select id="" onchange="" class="Sem_2" >
                    <option></option>
                    <option value="SP">SP</option>
                    <option value="AP">AP</option>
                    <option value="Guest">Guest</option>
                </select>
            </td>

            <td align="center">
                <select id="" onchange="" class="Sem_2" >
                    <option></option>
                    <option value="SP">SP</option>
                    <option value="AP">AP</option>
                    <option value="Guest">Guest</option>
                </select>
            </td>

            <td class="Sem_Secound">
                Total:
                <span class="cnt-total">0</span>
                <br/>    
                SP:
                <span class="cnt-sp">0</span>
                <br/>    
                AP:
                <span class="cnt-ap">0</span>
                <br/>    
                Guest:
                <span class="cnt-guest">0</span>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <b>Total</b>
            </td>

            <td class="Sem_first">
                Total:
                <span class="cnt-total">0</span>
                <br/>    
                SP:
                <span class="cnt-sp">0</span>
                <br/>    
                AP:
                <span class="cnt-ap">0</span>
                <br/>    
                Guest:
                <span class="cnt-guest">0</span>
            </td>

            <td class="Sem_Secound">
                Total:
                <span class="cnt-total">0</span>
                <br/>    
                SP:
                <span class="cnt-sp">0</span>
                <br/>    
                AP:
                <span class="cnt-ap">0</span>
                <br/>    
                Guest:
                <span class="cnt-guest">0</span>
            </td>

            <td class="total">
                <b>Total:
                    <span class="cnt-total">0</span>
                    <br/>    
                    SP:
                    <span class="cnt-sp">0</span>
                    <br/>    
                    AP:
                    <span class="cnt-ap">0</span>
                    <br/>    
                    Guest:
                    <span class="cnt-guest">0</span></b> 
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('select').change(function() {
            // get all selects
            var allSelects = $(this),
                total = 0,
                sp = 0,
                ap = 0,
                guest = 0;

            // for each select increase count
            $.each(allSelects, function(i, s) {
                // increase count
                if($(s).val() == 'SP') { total++ }
                if($(s).val() == 'AP') { total++ }
                if($(s).val() == 'Guest') { total++ }
                if($(s).val() == 'SP') { sp++; }
                if($(s).val() == 'AP') { ap++; }
                if($(s).val() == 'Guest') { guest++; }
            });

            // update count values summary
            if($(this).attr("class") == "Sem_1"){
                // For First Sem Row & column
                $(".Sem_first .cnt-total").text(total);
                $(".Sem_first .cnt-sp").text(sp);
                $(".Sem_first .cnt-ap").text(ap);
                $(".Sem_first .cnt-guest").text(guest);

            }
            if($(this).attr("class") == "Sem_2"){

                //For seound sem Row & column
                $(".Sem_Secound .cnt-total").text(total);
                $(".Sem_Secound .cnt-sp").text(sp);
                $(".Sem_Secound .cnt-ap").text(ap);
                $(".Sem_Secound .cnt-guest").text(guest);
            }      

            //For total

            $(".total .cnt-total").text(total);
            $(".total .cnt-sp").text(sp);
            $(".total .cnt-ap").text(ap);
            $(".total .cnt-guest").text(guest);

        });
```

Comment: here is the solution what you want

Comment: I have just provide core logic that how to different row and column not develop the calculation logic. so as per row click only this row and column will update that way I show it

Answer (score 0):

There is my solution without changind your html (except some syntax error from you) :

**HTML**

```
 <table>

 <tr><td><b>Sem I Honours</b></td><td align="center"><select  id="" onchange="" ><option></option><option      id="">SP</option><option id="">AP</option><option id="">Guest</option></select>  </td>

  <td align="center"><select  id=""  onchange=""><option></option>
 <option id="">SP</option><option id="">AP</option><option  id="">Guest</option>
</select></td>

 <td>Total:<span class="cnt-total">0</span><br/>SP:<span class="cnt-sp">0</span><br/>AP: <span class="cnt-ap">0</span><br/>Guest: <span class="cnt-guest">0</span></td></tr>


<tr><td><b>Sem III Honours</b></td>
<td align="center"><select   id="" onchange=""><option></option><option   id="">SP</option><option id="">AP</option><option id="">Guest</option></select></td>

<td align="center"><select   id="" onchange=""><option></option><option id="">SP</option><option id="">AP</option><option id="">Guest</option></select></td>

 <td>Total:<span class="cnt-total">0</span><br/>SP:<span class="cnt-sp">0</span><br/>AP: <span class="cnt-ap">0</span><br/>Guest: <span class="cnt-guest">0</span></td></tr>

 <tr><td><b>Total</b></td>


  <td>Total:<span class="cnt-total">0</span><br/>SP:<span class="cnt-sp">0</span><br/>AP: <span class="cnt-ap">0</span><br/>Guest: <span class="cnt-guest">0</span></td>

 <td>Total:<span class="cnt-total">0</span><br/>SP:<span class="cnt-sp">0</span><br/>AP: <span class="cnt-ap">0</span><br/>Guest: <span class="cnt-guest">0</span></td>

 <td><b>Total:<span class="cnt-total">0</span><br/>SP:<span class="cnt-sp">0</span><br/>AP: <span class="cnt-ap">0</span><br/>Guest: <span class="cnt-guest">0</span></b></td></tr>

</table>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var table = $("table")[0];

$('select').change(function() {
var row_index = $(this).parent().parent().index();
var col_index = $(this).parent().index();


var cell = table.rows[2].cells[1];
console.log(cell.id);

// get all selects
var allSelects = $('select');

// set values count by type
var totalx = 0;
var spx = 0;
var apx = 0;
var guestx = 0;

var totaly = 0;
var spy = 0;
var apy = 0;
var guesty = 0;

var total = 0;
var sp = 0;
var ap = 0;
var guest = 0;
// for each select increase count
$.each(allSelects, function(i, s) {
    // increase count

    var cur_x = $(this).parent().parent().index();
    var cur_y = $(this).parent().index();

    if (cur_x == row_index) {
      if($(s).val() == 'SP') { totalx++ }
      if($(s).val() == 'AP') { totalx++ }
      if($(s).val() == 'Guest') { totalx++ }
      if($(s).val() == 'SP') { spx++; }
      if($(s).val() == 'AP') { apx++; }
      if($(s).val() == 'Guest') { guestx++; }
    }
    if (cur_y == col_index) {
       if($(s).val() == 'SP') { totaly++ }
      if($(s).val() == 'AP') { totaly++ }
      if($(s).val() == 'Guest') { totaly++ }
      if($(s).val() == 'SP') { spy++; }
      if($(s).val() == 'AP') { apy++; }
      if($(s).val() == 'Guest') { guesty++; }
    }

      if($(s).val() == 'SP') { total++ }
      if($(s).val() == 'AP') { total++ }
      if($(s).val() == 'Guest') { total++ }
      if($(s).val() == 'SP') { sp++; }
      if($(s).val() == 'AP') { ap++; }
      if($(s).val() == 'Guest') { guest++; }

});

// update count values summary
$(table.rows[2].cells[col_index]).find(".cnt-total").text(totaly);
$(table.rows[row_index].cells[3]).find(".cnt-total").text(totalx);

$(table.rows[2].cells[col_index]).find(".cnt-sp").text(spy);
$(table.rows[row_index].cells[3]).find(".cnt-sp").text(spx);

$(table.rows[2].cells[col_index]).find(".cnt-ap").text(apy);
$(table.rows[row_index].cells[3]).find(".cnt-ap").text(apx);

$(table.rows[2].cells[col_index]).find(".cnt-guest").text(guesty);
$(table.rows[row_index].cells[3]).find(".cnt-guest").text(guestx);

$(table.rows[2].cells[3]).find(".cnt-total").text(total);
$(table.rows[2].cells[3]).find(".cnt-sp").text(sp);
$(table.rows[2].cells[3]).find(".cnt-ap").text(ap);
$(table.rows[2].cells[3]).find(".cnt-guest").text(guest);



});
```

And the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxg1nuew/) for live demo